# How to do row editing in ExtJS 6

Tags: java, extjs, extjs6

My project was in `ExtJS 4`, now I have upgraded it to `ExtJS 6`. But I have a problem in row editing. Can someone tell about the link where row editing is done in `ExtJS 6`. Due to upgrade to `ExtJS 6`, the row editing is not working.

Comment: What is error coming share them , your sample code also.

Comment: http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/classic/restful/restful.html

Comment: Please add code related to error.

Comment: See the guidelines on how to ask good questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

**Please go through following steps :-**

**Step 1. Add `requires` in your grid:**

`requires: [
        'Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing'
    ],`

**Step 2. In your grid, you need to use the following code:**

`selModel: 'rowmodel',
    plugins: [{
        pluginId: 'your_rowediting_plugin_id',
        ptype: 'rowediting',
        listeners: {
            cancelEdit: function(rowEditing, context) {
                // your stuff will go here
            },
            edit: function(editor, e) {
                // your stuff will go here
            }
        }
    }]`

Hope it will help/guide you.